# Assign the values of an array to a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, segmentation-fault

I am first concatenating a series of elements in an auxiliary `char` array to then assign the concatenated array to the pointer. The problem comes when assigning this `char` array to the pointer, where it produces a segmentation fault.

My approach was the following one:

```
char aux_name [12];
char * name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*13);
int i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sprintf(aux_name, "id_%i", i);
    *name = (void *) (intptr_t) aux_name; //Conflict line

   //Do something with variable name (it is required a pointer)

}
```

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Side note: what's the point in performing the exact same assignment 5 times???

Answer (score 1):

You don't *assign* a pointer value to an already `malloc()`-ed pointer, you'll be facing [memory-leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) there. You have to use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to achieve what you want.

OTOH, if you don't allocate memory dynamically, then you can assign the pointer like

```
name = aux_name;
```

That said,

> I am first concatenating a series of elements in an auxiliary char array

Well, you're not. you're simply overwriting the array every time in every iteration. What you need to do is

1. Collect the return value of [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) every time.
2. next iteration, advance the pointer to buffer by that many locations to *concatinate* the new input after the previous one.

Note / Suggestion:

1. [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. `sizeof(char)` is guranteed to be `1` in c standard. You don't need to use that, simply drop that part.

Comment: The remark about `sizeof(char)` is subjective. Some believe it should be there to make all malloc calls consistent. To use it or not is personal preference, there's no right or wrong (unlike casting the result of malloc, which is always bad/superfluous).

Comment: @Lundin sir, you're very right. But just as per one of the logics behind not casting `malloc()` result [the `It makes you repeat yourself, which is generally bad.` part], we can _suggest_ not to use `sizeof(char)`, isn't it? However, I updated my remark. Hope it is ok now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, and you don't really need to, this would work

```
size_t nonConstanSizeInBytes = 14;
char *name = malloc(nonConstanSizeInBytes);

snprintf(name, 13, "id_%i", i);
```